# Getting files from a Sony ICD-B600 onto Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: sound, microphone, audio-jack

I've got some files I'd love to get off of an old-ish voice recorder (Sony ICD-B600).
It only has mic and headphone jacks, no USB ports. I'm assuming I need a new driver (or possibly software? or some other sort of trick?) but I'm not sure what.
I'm not particularly concerned about sound quality at this point - any ideas for getting the files off the device would be great.

Comment: How did you get the audio off in the past? Are you sure there isn't a MicroSD card?

Comment: It's a family member's old recorder and she never needed the files on the computer. If there is an accessible MicroSD I certainly can't find it.

Comment: Okay, just checking. It's surprising how many questions get answered by people asking the dumb & seemingly obvious questions :D

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to connect the headphone jack of the voice recorder to the line in of your computer, and just record them playing. Example:

```
arecord recording1.wav
```

And then hit `CTRL-C` when it's done playing.  Do that for each one (or just record all of them into one recording) and you're done!